# .NET Core 6 migration external login error: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim<string>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using an external login script on a .NET Core 3.1 project. It takes an incoming token that contain a user email. If the Token is valid, it logs in the user. I followed the steps described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

It seems to work well in .NET Core 3.1, but it throws an error in .NET Core 6.

Here is the script responsible for the sign in:

```
public class SignInController : Controller
{
   private SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

   public TokenController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, MyProjectContext context)
   {
      _signInManager = signInManager;
      _context = context;
   }

   public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromQuery] string token)
   {
      //The token is passed to the controller via query string.
      //Both Core 3.1 and Core 6 successfully return an email from the following: 
      string emailFromToken = MyTokenParser.GetEmail(token);

      IdentityUser user = new()
      {
         UserName = emailFromToken,
         Email = emailFromToken,
         EmailConfirmed = true
      };

      //Core 6 cashes on the following code:
      await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, null);

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
}
```

When it crashes, it gives the following error message:

*InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoleClaims' for entity type 'IdentityRoleClaim' since it is being used for entity type 'AspNetRoleClaims' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'IdentityRoleClaim' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'AspNetRoleClaims'.*

Here is my context class. I used EF Core Power Tools to re-build it for Core 6 and made extra sure to check the 'include many-to-many' setting in the advanced options:

```
public partial class MyProjectContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public MyProjectContext()
    {
    }

    public MyProjectContext(DbContextOptions<MyProjectContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

            entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                .WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName, "RoleNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserTokens>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName, "UserNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");
        });
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
    }
}
```

Here is the IdentityUser class (it's the .NET Core default):

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The default implementation of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser`1 which
    //     uses a string as a primary key.
    public class IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string>
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
        public IdentityUser()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   userName:
        //     The user name.
        //
        // Remarks:
        //     The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
        public IdentityUser(string userName)
            : this()
        {
            UserName = userName;
        }
    }
}
```

Following the advice of the error message, I added a foreign key constraint:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

                entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).IsRequired();

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);

                //Tried to declare the relationship here
                entity.HasOne(d => d.RoleId)
                    .WithOne(p => p.*) //compiler error regardless of entry
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.*) //compiler error regardless of entry
            });
```

This causes a compiler error.

What am I missing here? How do I get this to work?

Comment: `IdentityDbContext<T>` already defines each dbset and their tables. What do your `AspNet*` types represent? Were you trying to customise each table to add new properties? Or did you try to reverse engineer the schema again?

Comment: Not much. The code runs perfectly well if I comment them out. The error remains the same regardless, so I thought I would include AspNet* for completeness.

Comment: The exception is informing you that after `OnModelCreating` you have duplicate types mapped to the same table. eg those defined by `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` and those you've defined in `MyProjectContext`, I assume by reverse engineering. IMHO you probably want to remove all traces of those `AspNet*` types from your project.

Comment: That appears to be the issue. Looks like I had to delete everything from AspNet* or it would throw the error. Commenting out `public virtual DbSet*` was insufficient. Now I'm getting new errors from other functions that worked better in Core 3.1. Sigh.